# Getting country name from visitors in a website

Tags: c#, geolocation, maxmind

I would like to know a way that I can get the Country Name of all the visitors who are visiting a website (my website). I have seen `maxmind.com` and it's so complicated to set it up as I am a beginner. Hope will get some good answers. I have already tried lots of things in this website and could not come up with a solution.

```
GeoServiceReference.GeocodeServiceClient client = new GeoServiceReference.GeocodeServiceClient();

var countries = new List<string>();

for (double lat = 0; lat < 360; lat+=0.1)
    for(double lon = 0; lon < 360; lon+=0.1)
    {
        var result = client.ReverseGeocode(new GeoServiceReference.ReverseGeocodeRequest
        {
            Location = new GeoServiceReference.Location
            {
                Latitude = lat,
                Longitude = lon
            }
        });

        if (!countries.Contains(result.Results.First().Address.CountryRegion))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Results.First().Address.CountryRegion);
            countries.Add(result.Results.First().Address.CountryRegion);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Maxmind, [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/) offers a free REST service that is based on Maxmind's legacy databases. It is very easy to use - you just need to issue an HTTP GET request to a URL in the following format:

```
http://freegeoip.net/json/{ip_or_hostname}
```

You could use a library like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) - again, very easy to use - to issue this request and parse the result.

Here's a simple example that should point you in the right direction:

```
public Geolocation GetGeolocationData(string ipAddress)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://freegeoip.net/");

    var request = new RestRequest("json/{ip}");
    request.AddUrlSegment("ip", ipAddress);

    var response = client.Execute<Geolocation>(request);
    return response.Data;
}
```

Here, I assume that `Geolocation` is a class with some properties that match the names of those in the JSON result returned by the REST service, e.g.:

```
public class Geolocation
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most handy tool is API or if you want to host the data and perform lookup at your server then you can consider to get a copy of database.
http://www.ipinfodb.com